# Cannot add data into django ManyToManyfield

Tags: django, model

I have this two models:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)


class User(AbstractUser):
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='followed_by')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Posts, related_name='liked_by')
    pass
```

And I want to add a post to someone`s `likes` field, so i do:

```
def change_like(request, post_id):
    post = Posts.objects.get(id=post_id)
    current_user = User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username).first()
    current_user.likes.add(post)
    print(post.liked_by)
    print(current_user.likes)
```

But it prints this:

```
network.User.None
network.Posts.None
```

Why is this happening? Am I adding the data correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is adding data into the ManyToMany Field. But you have printed using wrong method.

You can get all the likes of user by `current_user.likes.all()`.

Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/